# Why does JPanel.getGraphics() return null only when I restart the game? I have done everything I can think of to make it visible

Tags: java

I am making a minesweeper game to help me get acquainted with java graphics. When I draw the board for the first time and repeatedly in the Start() function, there is no problem. But when the game ends and you restart, the program produces a null pointer exception when trying to draw on the new jpanel.

The issue occurs when Start() is called from Replay() and draw() is called in Start(). Here is the exact error I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.Graphics.drawImage(java.awt.Image, int, int, java.awt.image.ImageObserver)" because "g" is null
        at Board.draw(Board.java:87)
        at Game.Start(Game.java:77)
        at Game.Replay(Game.java:123)
        at Game$Listener2.mouseClicked(Game.java:185)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6629)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4584)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

draw() method:

```
public void draw() {
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.Y; j++) {
                g.drawImage(board[i][j].getImage(), i * Game.WIDTH, j * Game.HEIGHT, null);
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
    }
```

Start() method:

```
private void Start() {
        System.out.println(gameListener.toString());        
        while (!end) {
            if (realFlags == 0) {
                win = true;
                end = true;
            }
            layout.draw();
        }
        layout.draw();
        End();
    }
```

Replay() method:

```
private void Replay() {
        window.removeAll();
        end = false;
        win = false;
        gameListener = new Listener();
        flags = BOMB_COUNT;
        realFlags = flags;

        window.addMouseListener(gameListener);

        window.setVisible(true);
        
        layout = new Board(this);

        Start();
    }
```

Full files:

Game.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game {
    private Board layout;

    //setup
    public static final int WIDTH = 40;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 40;
    public static final int X = 30;
    public static final int Y = 30;
    protected JFrame window;

    //game attributes
    public static final int BOMB_COUNT = 100;
    private int SCORE_BOARD_WIDTH = 100;
    private static boolean end = false;
    private boolean win = false;
    private static int flags;
    private static int realFlags;
    private Listener gameListener;

    public Game(String title) {
        gameListener = new Listener();
        window = new JFrame();
        flags = BOMB_COUNT;
        realFlags = flags;
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setSize(X * WIDTH, Y * HEIGHT);
        window.setLocation(1280 - (WIDTH * X) / 2, 720 - (HEIGHT * Y) / 2);
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.addMouseListener(gameListener);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        window.setVisible(true);

        layout = new Board(this);
        layout.draw();
        Start();
    }

    public static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int width, int height) throws IOException {
        Image resultingImage = originalImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
        BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        outputImage.getGraphics().drawImage(resultingImage, 0, 0, null);
        return outputImage;
    }

    private void Start() {
        System.out.println(gameListener.toString());        
        while (!end) {
            if (realFlags == 0) {
                win = true;
                end = true;
            }
            layout.draw();
        }
        layout.draw();
        End();
    }

    private void End() {
        gameListener = null;
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize( (int) window.getWidth() * 2 / 3, (int) window.getHeight() * 2 / 3);
        panel.setLocation(window.getWidth() / 2 - panel.getWidth() / 2, window.getHeight() / 2 - panel.getHeight() / 2);
        window.add(panel);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.setFont(new Font("tnr", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 100));
        if (win) {
            g.drawString("You Won!", 165, 200);
        } else {
            g.drawString("You Lost!", 175, 200);
        }
        g.drawString("Play Again?", 150, 400);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(50, 500, 700, 100);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Yes", panel.getWidth() / 2 - 100, 585);
        panel.addMouseListener(new Listener2());
        g.dispose();
    }

    private void Replay() {
        window.removeAll();
        end = false;
        win = false;
        gameListener = new Listener();
        flags = BOMB_COUNT;
        realFlags = flags;

        window.addMouseListener(gameListener);

        window.setVisible(true);
        
        layout = new Board(this);

        Start();
    }

    private void Close() {
        window.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void lose() {
        end = true;
        win = false;
        End();
    }

    public int getFlags() {
        return flags;
    }

    public void flagDown(boolean bomb) {
        flags--;
        if (bomb) realFlags--;
    }

    public void flagUp(boolean bomb) {
        flags++;
        if (bomb) realFlags++;
    }

public class Listener implements MouseListener {
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int i = e.getX() / Game.WIDTH, j = e.getY() / Game.HEIGHT;
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) 
        layout.Click(new Point(i, j));

        System.out.println("click @ (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ") (index [" + i + ", " + j + "])");

        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
        layout.Flag(i, j);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}

public class Listener2 implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getX() >= 50 && e.getX() <= 750 && e.getY() >= 500 && e.getY() <= 600)
            Replay();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}

}
```

Board.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board {

    private Game game;
    private JPanel panel;

    private Space[][] board = new Space[Game.X][Game.Y];
    public Board(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(Game.X * Game.WIDTH, Game.Y * Game.HEIGHT);
        panel.setLocation(0, 0);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        game.window.add(panel);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.Y; j++) {
                try {
                board[i][j] = new Space(false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        int rem = Game.BOMB_COUNT;
        while (rem > 0) {
            try {
                int i = (int) Math.floor(Game.X * Math.random()), j = (int) Math.floor(Game.Y * Math.random());
                if (!board[i][j].hasBomb()) {
                    board[i][j] = new Space(true);
                    rem--;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

        calculate();
    }

    private void calculate() {
        for (int x = 0; x < Game.X; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Game.Y; y++) {
                if (!board[x][y].hasBomb()) {
                    int count = 0;
                if (x > 0 && board[x - 1][y].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (x < Game.X - 1 && board[x + 1][y].hasBomb()) {
                    count ++;
                }   
                if (y > 0 && board[x][y - 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (y < Game.Y - 1 && board[x][y + 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (x > 0 && y > 0 && board[x - 1][y - 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (x < Game.X - 1 && y > 0 && board[x + 1][y - 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (x > 0 && y < Game.Y - 1 && board[x - 1][y + 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (x < Game.X - 1 && y < Game.Y - 1 && board[x + 1][y + 1].hasBomb()) {
                    count++;
                }
                board[x][y].setBombsNearby(count);
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw() {
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        for (int i = 0; i < Game.X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Game.Y; j++) {
                g.drawImage(board[i][j].getImage(), i * Game.WIDTH, j * Game.HEIGHT, null);
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
    }

    public void Click(Point p) {
        int i = (int) p.getX(), j = (int) p.getY();
        if (i >= Game.X || j >= Game.Y || i < 0 || j < 0) return;
        if (board[i][j].isCleared() || board[i][j].isFlagged()) return;
        if (board[i][j].hasBomb()) {
            try{
                board[i][j].clear();
                board[i][j].updateImage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            game.lose();
            return;
        }
            try {
                board[i][j].updateImage();
                board[i][j].clear();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (board[i][j].getBombsNearby() == 0) {
            Click(new Point(i - 1, j - 1));
            Click(new Point(i - 1, j));
            Click(new Point(i - 1, j + 1));
            Click(new Point(i, j - 1));
            Click(new Point(i, j + 1));
            Click(new Point(i + 1, j - 1));
            Click(new Point(i + 1, j));
            Click(new Point(i + 1, j + 1));
            }
        } 

    public void Flag(int i, int j) {
        if (i >= Game.X || j >= Game.Y || i < 0 || j < 0) return;
        if (board[i][j].isCleared()) return;
        if (game.getFlags() == 0) return;
        try {
            board[i][j].setFlagged(!board[i][j].isFlagged());
            if (board[i][j].isFlagged()) {
                board[i][j].setImage("src/img/Flag.png");
                game.flagDown(board[i][j].hasBomb());
        }
            else {
                board[i][j].setImage("src/img/Grass.png");
                game.flagUp(board[i][j].hasBomb());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Game("Minesweeper");
    }
}
```

I have made sure to set everything to visible and to delete the first JPanel. I have also made sure the second JPanel is properly instantiated. I read on another post that the component has to be visible to return a graphics object, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: You should not be calling `JPanel.getGraphics()`. What you should be doing  is subclassing `JPanel`  and overriding `JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)` .  Then do all your graphics in there.

Comment: Another useful option is to create a BufferedImage, get its graphics object via `getGraphics()`, and then draw the buffered image in paintComponent as mentioned by @WJS above. Also, remember to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in your own override and to read the appropriate tutorial on painting.

Comment: Any time that I have tried to do this it doesn't work as I expect. I was hoping I could still use JPanel.getGraphics(). Can you explain why I shouldn't use this?

Comment: Not certain what you mean by *`"it doesn't work as I expect"`*.   Take a look at the cited questions as well as many other examples of  how to paint on this site.

Comment: Check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).   Specificaly, [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: The duplicates will go into the details, but understand that a Graphics object obtained by calling `.getGraphics()` on a Swing component, such as a JPanel, will be short-lived and will be not-functioning with the next re-write. If you try to extract a Graphics object in this way prior to the component being rendered, it will be null. If you get it to work, if the OS re-draws the windows, your graphics will be broken. Just don't do it.

Comment: *"Can you explain why I shouldn't use this?"* because it's not how painting works in Swing - it can return `null`, it's only a snapshot of what was last painted and will be paint over on the next paint cycle. In Swing, you don't control when painting actually takes place and could take place at any time for any number of reasons, the best you can do is utilise `paintComponent` so you know when a paint cycle is taking place and when need, request a new paint pass using `repaint` - unless you want to make use of `Canvas` - but this is much more complicated subject

Comment: *The issue occurs when Start() is called from Replay() and draw()* - method names should NOT start with an upper case character. This is easily seen by method naming in the Java API. Some of your method names are correct, others are not. Be consistent and follow Java conventions.